# How do I resolve a versioning error when compiling spark scala project with sbt?

Tags: scala, apache-spark, sbt

I am working through the Apache Spark fundamentals course on pluralsight and trying to compile one of the example projects but am getting the following error. I have tried this now on two machines and am seeing the same thing. I can only assume this is some kind of versioning error for sbt and scala, and potentially spark?

I am using sbt 1.7.2, scala 2.12.15, spark 3.3.0

Any advice much appreciated!

````
[info] Updated file C:\Users\mg15\Documents\spark_stuff\LanguageEvaluator - PreTransform\project\build.properties: set sbt.version to 1.7.2
[info] welcome to sbt 1.7.2 (Oracle Corporation Java 16)
[info] loading settings for project languageevaluator-pretransform-build from assembly.sbt,plugins.sbt ...
[info] loading project definition from C:\Users\mg15\Documents\spark_stuff\LanguageEvaluator - PreTransform\project
[warn]
[warn]  Note: Some unresolved dependencies have extra attributes.  Check that these dependencies exist with the requested attributes.
[warn]          com.eed3si9n:sbt-assembly:1.7.2 (sbtVersion=1.0, scalaVersion=2.12)
[warn]          com.typesafe.sbteclipse:sbteclipse-plugin:4.0.0 (sbtVersion=1.0, scalaVersion=2.12)
[warn]
[warn]  Note: Unresolved dependencies path:
[error] sbt.librarymanagement.ResolveException: Error downloading com.eed3si9n:sbt-assembly;sbtVersion=1.0;scalaVersion=2.12:1.7.2```
````

Comment: @AminMal the question is Scala related, not Java related

Comment: Marc, can you add your sbt file? I think you might be using a wrong dependency or scala version (2 and 3 sometimes seem to have conflicts in libraries available to them)

Comment: Thanks all. I don't think this is a Java issue. On my other machine it's definitely using Java 8 and I'm getting the exact same error messages after.

Comment: The build.sbt file is as follows:
```name := "Language Evaluator"

version := "0.1"

scalaVersion := "2.12.15"

libraryDependencies += "org.apache.spark" %% "spark-core" % "3.3.0" % "provided"

libraryDependencies += "org.apache.hadoop" % "hadoop-streaming" % "3.2.2"

assemblyJarName in assembly := s"${name.value.replace(' ','-')}-${version.value}.jar"

assemblyOption in assembly := (assemblyOption in assembly).
                                    value.copy(includeScala = false)```

Comment: @AminMal I'm running Java11 and 18  and I have never had any issues like that. SBT is independent of the JDK, it's compiled code. Also don't call me "dude", I'm not your "dude".

Comment: assemblyJarName in assembly := s"${name.value.replace(' ','-')}-${version.value}.jar <- The console says to you that it cannot find the version for: scalaVersion=2.12:1.7.2; This is because the latest version is for Scala 2.8.1 (It's actually quit old).. Maven repo link is here: https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.eed3si9n/sbt-assembly_2.8.1/sbt0.10.1_0.6

Comment: Can you share your `plugins.sbt` as well? SBT assembly latest version is 1.2.0, you probably made a typo.

Comment: Thanks all for your help. I can confirm the issue was with the SBT assembly version. I had been advised elsewhere this should match the version of SBT. Altered this to instead look for 0.14.10, and the program now compiles.